Unable to update id with JQuery without refreshing the page
I want to implement a function that allows the user to click on a cell and have it dynamically update and add a value into a database. It is working as intended, but I cannot get it to work without refreshing the page or using location.reload()
I want to change the cell with the class = .submitChange (near the bottom)
<tr>
    <th scope='row'><?php echo $row['lastname'] . ", " . $row['firstname']; ?></th>
    <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['usertype']; ?></td>
    <?php
    foreach ($events_array as $event) { 
        $event_date = $event['date'];
        $employee_id = $row['id'];
        
        // Check if employee has a vacation day
        $vacation_day = false;
        foreach ($vacation_dates[$employee_id] as $vacation_date) {
            if ($vacation_date == $event_date) {
                $vacation_day = true;
                break; 
            }
        }
        
        // Check if employee is working that day
        $sql_check_worker = "SELECT * FROM Workers WHERE employee={$row['id']} AND event={$event['id']}";
        $result_check_worker = $smeConn->query($sql_check_worker);
        if ($result_check_worker->num_rows > 0) { // displays cell color if employee is working or not
            $serverSum++;
            $cellColorId = 'green-cell';
        } else {
            $cellColorId = 'yellow-cell';
        }
        ?>
        <?php if ($vacation_day) { 
            echo "<td class='vacation'></td>"; 
        } else {
            echo "<td id='$cellColorId' class='submitChange' data-eventid='{$event['id']}' data-employeeid='{$row['id']}'></td>";
        }
        ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <td><?php echo $serverSum; ?></td>
</tr>

Here is my jquery:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.submitChange').click(function() {
        $cellId = $(this).attr('id');
        $eventId = $(this).data('eventid');
        $employeeId = $(this).data('employeeid');
        if ($cellId === 'green-cell') {
            $action = 'remove';
        } else {
            $action = 'add';
        }
        console.log($cellId)
        $.ajax({
            url:"includes/ajax_request.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:{
                action:$action,
                eventId:$eventId,
                employeeId:$employeeId
            },
            success:function(response){
                if (response === 'removed') {
                    $(this).removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'yellow-cell'); // Remove old ID and set new one
                    alert("Employee has been removed from event!");
                } else {
                    $(this).removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'green-cell'); // Remove old ID and set new one
                    alert("Employee has been added to event!");
                }  
            }
        })
    })
});

If it's relevant, here is my ajax script:
<?php

include("connect.php");
$action = $_POST['action'];
$eventId = $_POST['eventId'];
$employeeId = $_POST['employeeId'];

if ($action === 'remove') {
    $sql = "DELETE FROM Workers WHERE event = $eventId AND employee = $employeeId";
    $smeConn->query($sql);
    echo "removed";
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Workers (event, employee) VALUES ($eventId, $employeeId)";
    $smeConn->query($sql);
    echo "added";
}

?>

The function is working as intended; the data is being added into my database and the cell is changing colors, however, it only works after I refresh the page.

$(this) in the success function is not what you expect.

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should never concatenate values directly into a query.

Warning: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by PDO or by MySQLi. Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, you are still in risk of corrupting your data. Escaping is not enough!

As @grumpycrouton mentioned this does not mean what you expect in that context.
Please try something like this:
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.submitChange').click(function (ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();

    var cell = ev.target;
    $cellId = $(cell).attr('id');
    $eventId = $(cell).data('eventid');
    $employeeId = $(cell).data('employeeid');
    if ($cellId === 'green-cell') {
        $action = 'remove';
    } else {
        $action = 'add';
    }
    console.log($cellId)
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/ajax_request.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            action: $action,
            eventId: $eventId,
            employeeId: $employeeId
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response === 'removed') {
                $(cell).removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'yellow-cell'); // Remove old ID and set new one
                alert("Employee has been removed from event!");
            } else {
                $(cell).removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'green-cell'); // Remove old ID and set new one
                alert("Employee has been added to event!");
            }
        }
    })
  })
});


Thank you. That worked, the cell colors are updating automatically on click. However, the database still isn't being updated without refreshing, which is a whole other issue I believe.
